# sonarRunner java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, error-handling, sonarqube, permgen, sonar-runner

**Environment:**

1. Linux

2. Gradle 1.6/7

3. Language - Java

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport - working fine.

Recently followed the documentation provided by SonarQube installation at: 
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Linux
(sonar start, sonar status, sonar stop etc)...commands will work at this point.

Changed gradle build script acc. to Gradle SonarRunner help page at:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html

**While running sonarRunner task - I get the following error:**

```
:sonarRunner
18:56:03.997 INFO  - Load batch settings
18:56:04.140 INFO  - User cache: /production/c123456/jenkins/.sonar/cache
18:56:04.146 INFO  - Install plugins
18:56:04.851 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
18:56:04.858 WARN  - H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
18:56:04.858 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://devserver11.tr.company.com:9092/sonar
18:56:05.870 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
:sonarRunner FAILED
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
> Building-bash-3.2$
```

Installed sonar at /production/c123456/sonar i.e.
- sonar/conf/sonar.properties - everything looks correct
- sonar/conf/wrapper.properties - contains valid values for JAVA opts i.e.

```
# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

# RECOMMENDED : uncomment if Java Virtual Machine is a JDK but not a JRE. To know which JVM you use, execute
# 'java -version'. JDK displays 'Server VM'.
wrapper.java.additional.4=-server

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=512

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
```

1. Can someone help what I could be missing to get this error message - PermGen space issue
   **NOTE**: This was happening from one Linux machine, so I tried installing Sonar on other Linux 
        machine, still got the same error message.
2. I installed SonarQube/Runner on my own local Windows machine and pointed build.gradle sonarRunner section to use host url as my local machine / host url my machine name (fqdn) with port (:9000) etc and same for jdbc h2 tcp way.

   While running "gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner", it passes the above error but gives me another strange one. C:\work is my workspace where I have checked out the project: Project_A_Svc (service project - Java source).

   :sonarRunner FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   - What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.

     > org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: The folder 'C:\work\Project_A_Svc\src\main\java' does not exist for 'project_a_svc:project_a_svc' project (base directory = C:\work\Project_A_Svc)
   - Try:
     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

   BUILD FAILED

   Total time: 38.124 secs

**Why Gradle** is trying to look for "src/main/java" when my source code doesn't even have that folder structure. Gradle default structure is to use "src/main/java" for java source code location but my build.gradle does have sourceSets section where I have mentioned the location to find java source. I have tried multiple ways to set source Dirs for src java / tests but it's still trying to look for "src/main/java".

**build.gradle** snapshost

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

   main {
      java {
         srcDir 'src/java'
      }
   }
   test {
      java {
         srcDir 'test/java'
      }
   }
   integrationTest {
      java {
         srcDir 'src/java-test'
      }
   }
}
```

and

**sonarRunner section** within build.gradle is:

```
def sonarServerUrl = "devserver11.tr.company.com"
sonarRunner {
   sonarProperties {
      property "sonar.host.url", "http://$sonarServerUrl:9000"
  // these are default settings for the in-memory database.  Change if using a persistent DB.
  property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:tcp://$sonarServerUrl:9092/sonar"
  property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "org.h2.Driver"
  property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
  property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"

  //properties ["sonar.sources"] += sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  //properties ["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
  //----
  properties["sonar.sources"] = "src/java"
  properties["sonar.tests"] = "test/java"

   }
}
```

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some progress.

**Steps**

1. DIDN'T change anything in sonar/conf/sonar.properties, wrapper.properties, sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties. MADE sure the host url value is same in sonar.properties and sonar-runner.properties.
2. Go to the workspace (where you have source code installed).
3. Ran
   **sonar-runner** (an executable) - it will show the path/file
   It gave the error that I need *sonar-project.properties* as I was missing some variables required 
   by Sonar.

   Used the [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)
4. Found SCM Provider not set. Used the link: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ACT-1714 to resolve it.
5. ran sonar-runner again, it went fine. (NOTE: This command is different than running sonarRunner as that's Gradle's sonar runner task).
6. Went to SonarQube dashboard and there's stuff showing now.

**PENDING for tomorrow:**

6. To the following at Linux command line and from Jenkins (job calling gradle tasks).
   **gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner**

**Update:**

- Tried running:

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport - works

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner -- Fails saying src/main/java doesn't exist

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources=src/java -- WORKED

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources="src/java,test/java,src/java-test" -- DID NOT WORKED (PermGen java error)

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources="src/java" -- DID NOT WORKED (PermGen java error)

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources=src/java -- DID NOT WORKED (PermGen java error)

gradle sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources=src/java,test/java,src/java-test -- DID NOT WORKED (Error is charset can't read or import - charset UTF-8 or whatever I end up setting for sonar.sourceEncoding)

*gradle clea build jacocoTestReport* -- WORKED

**then**

*gradle sonarRunner -Dsonar.sources="src/java"* -- WORKED

I have tried setting MaxPernGen in sonar/conf/wrapper.properties to various values like 128, 512, 1024, 2048, ... upto 8000m ... didn't work in resolving the following error - while running all gradle tasks in one command.

```
:sonarRunner FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**Wondering why I'm getting this error as soon as I run:**

:gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner"

**OK** - got PermGen Memory issue **resolved.**

**Steps**:
1. In my ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile. I created the following variable

```
GRADLE_OPTS=” -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

2. Run "which gradle" or basically find which gradle file (shell or .bat) is used. Go to that path and open "gradle" / "gradle.bat" (for windows) file.
3. Make the following changes.

   ```
   DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS"
   ```
4. Do ". ~/.bash_profile" or ". ~/.bashrc" .... --OR open a new putty session.
5. Make sure PATH variable has gradle HOME / bin in it (Linux/Windows)
6. Ran the following command (this time didn't show PermGen error which I got earlier) from workspace:

   gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner

   **:) Time to go home early today.**
7. Other similar variables are: GRADLE_OPTS / JAVA_OPTS / SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS (where -XX:Max.. value can be set) at server(putty session level) or in IDEs or in Jenkins.

Thanks Allyn for the hint.

Comment: So, 1 work around is: to call gradle two times with different tasks within a job.

Comment: This workaround won't work - as Jenkins Gradle plugin has a BUG - invoking 2 calls of "invoke gradle script" in build section, makes the first call to hide "Gradle version" list box/box. I'll raise a ticket.

Comment: See final answer for resolving PermGen Java memory space issue.

Comment: NOTE: This worked only at command line level. While calling the same Gradle tasks within Jenkins job under Build > Invoke Gradle Script section, I got Java PermGen output space error.

Comment: 17:03:41 :sonarRunner FAILED
17:03:41 
17:03:41 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:03:41 
17:03:41 * What went wrong:
17:03:41 Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
17:03:41 > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
17:03:41 
17:03:41 * Try:
17:03:41 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
17:03:41 
17:03:41 BUILD FAILED

Comment: The above is resolved as well. While starting Jenkins, set JAVA_OPTS as: export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Gradle Wrapper, you can specify GRADLE_OPTS there, which should work on Jenkins as well.