# Android Robolectric Gradle - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: android, gradle, out-of-memory, robolectric

I have an android project setup with robolectric tests with a total of around 2084 unit tests right now. But I have been running into issues adding more tests because of the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`.

```
objc[11380]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space                        
Exception in thread "Test worker" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
:app:testDebug FAILED
```

with the strack trace, I get the following

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java
...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.stop(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.endBatch(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.stop(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
...
```

In my `gradle.properties in the root directory and my module directory, I tried putting the following and nothing worked. I still get the out of memory problem.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m
```

I have tried the options from [Android Studio Gradle Issue: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://www.answerques.com/smm1gQqgeXgS/android-studio-gradle-issue-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) still no luck. I also have been looking at [sonarRunner java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499829/sonarrunner-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space).

Hope to get some help on this. Thanks

Comment: you have check https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space ?

Comment: Thank you @Abdellah. What I understand is that I have a lot of classes, methods and what not hat overload the PermGen. The information is very useful. So what can I do about this right now? I am mocking a lot of objects in my unit tests and spying as well. My Android project makes use of a lot of libraries which means bringing in a lot of classes and methods as well.

Comment: Respect for 2048 tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that I have gathered.

Abdellah gave some insight on the problem and it has to do with the number of total classes created. 
"you have check https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space "

Eugen Martynov also mentioned the parameter from the robolectric gradle plugin configuration that I can add. Link at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin#configuration-using-dsl

The main problem with my code is that with a limited PermGen space, I was creating a lot of Spy objects in Mockito which seems to be eating up most of the space.

Answer (score 8):

Try a bigger number than 512m : `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms512m`

## Edit

As @Eugen Martynov mention If you use **robolectric gradle plugin**, you can specify them as [`DSL` *configuration*](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin#configuration-using-dsl)

Comment: Do robolectric tests inherit these params from gradle? If you use robolectric gradle plugin, you can specify them in `build.gradle` https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin#configuration-using-dsl

Comment: This comment seems to have the answer in conjuction with Abdellah's answer.

Answer (score 0):

the answer should be(at least for me):

```
subprojects {
  tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 2
    forkEvery = 80
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
    minHeapSize = "1024m"
  }
}
```

refer from:https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5131